# Regular expression to strip filename

Tags: c#, regex

I have several files in a folder with following convention:

```
1. Size-2.125-in-0.3083-in.pdf
2. Size-0.1-in-0.3083-in.something.pdf
3. Size-2.11-in-0.3083-in.someotherthing.pdf
```

As you can see the values after decimal point are not of fixed number. How can I strip this filename using Regular Expressions. I also only need the file that is .pdf (number 1 in this case). All the other files which doesn't resembles the 1 filename should be ignored.

I was using this regular expression but it fails if number of decimal places change.

```
Size-......-in-......-in.pdf
```

I am using C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `@"Size-\S+-in-\S+-in\.pdf"`

Comment: You should post the regular expression you've been trying to use, next time.

Answer (score 0):

This: `^Size-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-in-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-in\.pdf$`

should be enough. In capture groups 1 and 2 you have your numbers. Everything else is fixed so I don't capture it.

Tester: http://regexr.com?35t0c

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^Size-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-in-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-in\.pdf$");
var match = rx.Match("Size-2.125-in-0.3083-in.pdf");

Console.WriteLine("Success: {0}", match.Success);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Full string: {0}, group 1: {1}, group 2: {2}", 
        match.Groups[0].ToString(), 
        match.Groups[1].ToString(), 
        match.Groups[2].ToString());
}
```